# Windows 8.1 on ThinkPad S540 plagued by frequent BSODs with error CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED

Tags: windows-8.1, bsod, thinkpad

I'm running Windows 8.1 on a Lenovo ThinkPad S540 laptop, and I encounter very frequent BSODs (even 3-4 times per day!), where the error code is always `CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED`. No further information seem to be available, and the Windows event log only mentions an unexpected shutdown, not its actual cause.

The system has been doing this since its initial setup 3 months ago; I've installed every available update both from Microsoft and from the product vendor, but nothing seems to fix it.

I've also checked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/496253/windows-8-critical-process-died), but this computer has a Samsung SSD disk, and anyway its firmware is already at the latest available version.

How can I fix thix?

Comment: You are running the current version of UEFI firmware correct?

Comment: Yes, all firmwares have been updated with the latest releases from the vendor.

Comment: Have you used the Samsung SSD tools to determine if its working within its specifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out something was indeed faulty in the computer: today it suddenly declared there was no hard disk installed, and just refused to boot.

The disk is actually fine, it works flawlessly when connected to an external USB dock.